# Django - How to carry the filters to the next view?

Tags: django

I imagine something like this is possible in Django, but I don't know how to implement it:

I have a TableView, which has filters to filter the displayed queryset. I, then, have a DetailView which you can access from the TableView, to see the details of each element in the queryset.

The DetailView has a form, which uses the POST method. I can successfully send the form, and redirect to the TableView after the POST call. My question is, how can I make it so that after the user calls the POST method in the DetailView, and it redirects again to the TableView, the TableView keeps whichever values were on its filters?

I imagine I would have to either get access to the full request on the TableView (because it includes the ?param1=?param2= etc.), or be able to send the values in the filters when I call the DetailView.

Comment: You have access to the full request, the querysetring is stored in `request.GET`.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me however why you use a POST request. Normally that is only done to *alter* the state of the app, or to send sensitive data. Exactly because a GET request encodes the data in the URL, and thus makes it easy to for example copy-paste the URL and retrieve the same search results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the POST data is stored in `request.data`. This should be stored in a dictionary so you could iterate through request.data with a for loop to extract the posted data into variables. Then you can do whatever with those variables.